# Enable Hazelcast SPI object via spring

Tags: spring, hazelcast

I am working on some new custom distributed objects to run in Hazelcast SPI.

As can be seen in : http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/spiaddproperties.html you can enable via the Hazelcast xml config, or of course, you can enable programmatically.

It appears that the spring hazelcast xml schema does not support SPI creation, and I would like to create/enable and inject spring beans as properties to the new service.

Can anyone advise if this is possible? I want to utilize spring to instantiate the hazelcast instance as this is the most robust way I've found to do so in a large application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is supported.
You can find an example here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast-spring/src/test/resources/com/hazelcast/spring/fullcacheconfig-applicationContext-hazelcast.xml#L309

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that quorum was also in that xml, and that came out with 3.5 I think, so I upgraded to 3.5 and it works properly now.